# How to show value in a cell only if current month

Tags: excel

My first time here, my question is this:

I have 6 cells lets say A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2  each cell value is driven by formula.

Above each of those cells I have named months like A1=October, B1=November, C1=December, D1=January, E1=February, F2=March.

What i want to do is show the value of A2 since we are in October but don't show the value of B2, C2, D2, E2, and F2, then once we are in November still show the value of A2 and B2 but not the rest, once December show A2, B2, C2 and so on.

The formula I'm using now is this:

```
=IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=10,(C27+D24)-(Q15+E35),"0")
```

It works all good but when it comes to December and January I cant get it to work. If I use `=IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=12` it wont show the value of December which is good but once January rolls in then the value of December will show 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, one more thing I can not use a macro. Thanks again

Comment: Why not put actual dates, like `11/1/2013` in row 1 and format them like "mmm-yyyy"? Then you could just compare whether `Today` was less than the first of each month.

Comment: Thank you Doug I finally got it working using your idea, at first I wasn't sure how that is done but after playing around I figured it out, thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :).

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like that for October:

```
=IF(TODAY()>=("1-"&A1&"-2013")*1,(C26+D23)-(U14+E34),0)
```

And when you reach January, you only have to change the year in `("1-"&A2&"-2013")*1` to `"-2014"`. `("1-"&A2&"-2013")*1` by the way generates a date value by concatenating 1, the month and the year and the *1 is what converts the text to a date.

What I actually added is a check to see if `TODAY()` was greater than or equal to the first of the specific month. So that now, both the month and the date must be greater than or equal to that specific month.

[Excel spreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dFVDdFBFbmxxZzlKRncyaERUMS1iRWc#gid=1)

Comment: Thank you for your help, what I have right now once I reach January will work, the problem I have is that I can see all the calculations now, but they will not show once we are in January. Once I finish my workbook I have to send it to someone else, I can't edit anymore and the person I'm preparing for can not change anything.

Comment: I'll try and explain one more time what I have, Cell B2 contains this formula =IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=10,(A2+E34)-(E35),"0") Cell C2 contains this formula =IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=11,(B2+F34)-(F35),"0") Cell D2 contains this formula =IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=12,(C2+G34)-(G35),"0") Cell E2 contains this formula =IF(MONTH(TODAY())>=1,(D2+H34)-(H35),"0")

Comment: @Agron Hi, sorry about the late reply. I had difficulties getting online due to various things that happened to me at the same time. I simplified the formula and provided a test spreadsheet to show you how it is working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=IF(DATEVALUE(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmmyyyy"))>=DATEVALUE(A1&IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&1))>COLUMN(),2013,2014)),(C27+D24)-(Q15+E35),"")
```

**Update 1:**
this returns a value (number) representing October2013:

```
DATAVALUE(TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmmyyyy") 'returns 41548
```

Now you compare it with this formula:

```
DATEVALUE(A1&IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&1))>COLUMN(),2013,2014))
```

The above formula concatenates values of A1 to either 2013 or 2014.
If `MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&1)` is greater than `COLUMN()` it returns 2013 and 
concatenates it to A1 value, 2014 otherwise.

So since current month is OCTOBER, the above formula would yield:

```
MONTH(DATEVALUE(A1&1) 'returns 10
COLUMN() 'returns 1 since formula is in A2
```

So A1 value (OCTOBER) concatenates to 2013. 
And thus returns 41548 as well after evaluated by `DATEVALUE`.

For JANUARY:

```
MONTH(DATEVALUE(D1&1) 'returns 1
COLUMN() 'returns 4 since formula is in D2
```

D2 value (JANUARY) joins with 2014 instead.
This returns  41640 which is still greater than DECEMBER2013 value which is 41609.

Just one formula.
What I did is to add year to the month and then compare it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: L42, I'm not sure I understand your solution,I just want to be clear that the formula I'm looking for I have to enter in cell A2 not A1, like B2 for Nov, C2 for Dec, D2 for Jan, and so on, the cells above (A1, B1, C1 etc) the are just text written Like October, November they are not written in English tho, i tried your solution I cant get it to work.

Comment: Hi Agron. yes you put that formula in A2 since you have the month names in A1 through F1. I can't see why it won't work. I added explanation on the formula I posted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply L42, I tried I can't get it working using your solution, the only thing I can think of is that as I said the month names in A1 through F1 they are not written in English (like October is Tetor) that's in Albanian, I got this working 100% the way I wanted using @Portland Runner solution. I created months format column from B46 to B57 then I used this formula for October `=IF(B46<=TODAY(),(A2+E34)-(E35),"0")` and so on for the rest of the months, thank you again for your help.

Comment: not a problem Agron. the good thing is we learned something new in the process. :) you're always welcome.